# Ionic serve sometimes can't find ngForm or other things

Tags: ionic-framework

I'm using Ubuntu and building projects with Inoic. Sometimes when I run the

```
ionic serve
```

command, I get an error like so:

```
Cannot find name 'ngForm'.
```

I then stop the Ionic and re-run the command to fix it. I just had to do this four times for Ionic to not throw this error; I didn't change any code at all, just restarting over and over. Is there a fix for this?